# How to remove seasonality?

Tags: seasonality, vector-error-correction-model

I'm trying to do a VECM with these two monthly variables. I applied the Johansen test and they are cointegrated.

[image]
[image]

As you see, they have a hard seasonality component. Should I apply a filter to remove seasonality before the VECM? If yes, wich one? I was thinking in Hodrick-Prescott filter.

I really appreciate your help. This is for my final grade project.

Answer (score 2):

In your data, we can see a clear trend in the series - aside from the peaks and valleys that we observe due to seasonality.

In this regard, given that you are trying to test cointegration - examining the trend between the two time series would be sufficient for this purpose. The premise of cointegration is that the time series will converge regardless of short-term divergence as a result of seasonality.

Consider a stock price:

[image: price time series]

Assume the data frame for the above is called `pricetimeseries`.

Here is how we can decompose this series in R:

```
pricetimeseriescomponents <- decompose(pricetimeseries)
plot(pricetimeseriescomponents)
```

Here is a plot of the time series components, with plots of the observed, trend, seasonal, and random components:

[image: decompose]

Suppose you wish to extract the trend component - you would do so as follows:

```
> pricetimeseriescomponents$trend
           Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May
2005        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
2006  522.4662  529.3182  534.8247  541.8366  548.0212
2007  593.4455  601.4741  615.8859  629.7638  641.6483
2008  733.6673  743.6278  752.2227  766.4457  787.9554
2009  965.6929  996.8343 1027.5245 1055.4893 1080.0541
2010 1351.7832 1372.8470 1391.3127 1403.0279 1412.5826
2011 1527.3403 1553.4908 1579.0567 1605.7978 1637.1384
2012 1915.9968 1954.4039 2000.5238 2043.3551 2074.7826
2013 2122.9231 2159.4696 2190.1142 2235.0433 2301.6488
2014 3011.0224 3065.9748 3124.0549 3182.1676 3230.7467
2015        NA                                        
           Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep       Oct
2005        NA  514.7937  514.4616  515.6833  517.4935
2006  552.2900  558.2910  563.3892  565.7217  571.3616
2007  652.8290  662.4862  672.6203  683.4498  694.0758
2008  811.8698  835.3667  858.7176  881.3508  899.9198
2009 1107.9877 1144.7267 1186.2736 1226.7556 1264.7067
2010 1424.5948 1436.3032 1453.0420 1471.7128 1482.5863
2011 1669.3786 1703.6051 1726.6751 1749.0592 1789.6872
2012 2089.7982 2087.0113 2082.9266 2077.2431 2070.2600
2013 2380.8170 2464.3157 2553.0360 2651.3149 2753.5820
2014 3279.1748 3328.5332        NA        NA        NA
2015                                                  
           Nov       Dec
2005  517.1992  517.5922
2006  580.4228  588.1642
2007  705.7303  720.1067
2008  917.9098  938.9571
2009 1298.6959 1328.0321
2010 1492.7199 1506.7854
2011 1829.7861 1872.8303
2012 2076.1825 2092.9732
2013 2852.7439 2941.1436
2014        NA        NA
2015
```

Here is a plot:

[image: trend]

We can see that the overall trend still remains, but the "peaks and valleys" that we saw in the first graph no longer remain.

In this regard, you might try extracting the trends in your time series using R and then using VECM.

Comment: I'm using STATA. So, Are filters such as Hodrick-Prescott or Baxter-King right?

Comment: The Hodrick-Prescott filter is known to remove cyclical data from a time series, so should have similar results to what I described above. You could try this and see what the results are.